# Docker compose connection refused

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am getting a 'connection refused' error when trying to hit my NodeJS server running in a Docker container. If I try to cURL the server from the host machine, I get the error "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer".

When I run `sudo docker-compose up -d` it starts up my services and running `sudo docker ps -a` shows the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e56b30b1de9c        mongo:4.1.8-xenial   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   27017/tcp                db
0d82b0a881e5        nodejs               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   nodejs
```

The containers are running on a server with IP '192.168.0.24' so I try to hit an endpoint in my 'nodejs' app via '192.168.0.24:3000/items' but this results in a connection refused error.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=db
      - MONGO_PORT=$MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_DB=$MONGO_DB
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/app
      - /home/node/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: ./wait-for.sh db:27017 -- /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js
  db:
    image: mongo:4.1.8-xenial
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
  node_modules:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./
USER node
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=node:node . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "app.js" ]
```

Comment: What host OS/environment is Docker running in? Is there a firewall (software or hardware) enabled?

Comment: Also can you get to port 3000 in the container from the Docker host without going over the network? Just using localhost?

Comment: @doublesharp I'm running Docker on a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 20.04. `curl localhost:3000` returns 'curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer'. I ran `ufw status` to check firewalls but it responded with 'Status: inactive'.